# How to run migration scripts for a corda node running inside the docker container?

Tags: docker, corda

The official docker image for Corda uses a `run-corda` command to start the node. However, sometimes the node needs to be configured first before starting up. An example would be to run database migration scripts when new schemas are introduced by new CorDapps. How can I run such commands first before starting up the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered on Corda's Slack channel. I'll just move it here.

The problem can be solved by overriding the image's start-up command (`run-corda`) with the following:

```
command: sh -c "java -jar /etc/corda/jar/corda.jar run-migration-scripts --core-schemas --app-schemas --base-directory=/opt/corda --config-file=/etc/corda/node.conf; java -jar /etc/corda/jar/corda.jar --config-file=/etc/corda/node.conf
```

Depending on corda's version, the directory name may be slightly different.

See an [example Dockerfile](https://github.com/corda/bank-in-a-box/blob/release/bankinabox/1.0/docker/corda-node/Dockerfile)